# Assigning json array to interface when string[] does not work

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following json file which holds a list of blacklist terms.

```
{
  "blacklist": [
    "term1",
    "term2",
    "term3",
    "term4",
    "term5"
   ]
}
```

It is used in blacklist service:

```
@Injectable()
export class BlacklistService {
  private readonly BLACKLIST_TERMS_FOLDER = './assets/data/web-blacklist-terms';
  private readonly blacklistTerms1: any;
  private readonly blacklistTerms2: any;
}

constructor(
  public httpClient: HttpClient
) {
  this.blacklistTerms1 = this.httpClient.get(`${this.BLACKLIST_TERMS_FOLDER}/terms.json`);
}


public getAllBlackListTerms(): Observable<any> {
  return combineLatest([this.blacklistTerms1, this.blacklistTerms2])
}
```

How would I add a type to `blacklistTerms`? I have tried string[] but it gives me the message `Type 'Observable ' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 27 more.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about you add a interface like this at top of your class

```
interface BlackList{
   blacklist: string[]
}
```

And use it in your code as

```
this.blacklistTerms1: Observable<BlackList>  = this.httpClient.get<BlackList>(`${this.BLACKLIST_TERMS_FOLDER}/terms.json`);
```

If you want to reuse the interface in other components it would be ideal to move it in another file where you place other interfaces as well and import it from there.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.httpClient.get(`${this.BLACKLIST_TERMS_FOLDER}/terms.json`)
    .subscribe(x => this.blacklistTerms1 = x);
```

You are trying to assign a Observable to a string[]. Does not work. Use subscribe.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I now get the error `Error:(39, 82) TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?`

Comment: Console.log(x) and check what you get. I would prefer to have the method in ngoninit also. By the sound of it looks like You’re not getting an array.

Comment: I get an array:  `"blacklist": [
    "term1",
    "term2",
    "term3",
    "term4",
    "term5"
   ]`

Comment: x[”blacklist”] then.